# Unable to create Kubernetes Cluster on IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I have been trying to create a Kubernetes Cluster with my Bluemix account owner but always getting the following error upon creation:

*IBM Cloud Infrastructure exception: Your account is currently prohibited from order 'Computing Instances'.*

Any idea what the issue is?  There seems to be no direct way to getting support from Public Bluemix to address this issue.  We opened a ticket but it has not been addressed.

Answer (score 0):

You should contact IBM Bluemix Support for this kind of question.  Before you login to the Bluemix Console, there is a Support link.

From the look of the exception.  It seen like you are trying to create a "second" kubernetes cluster.  If this is what you are trying to do, you will need a SoftLayer account; or your ID in your SoftLayer account is not setup properly.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  We have opened a ticket on this a while ago using the Support link but weren't able to get anyone to respond to it.  Is there some way to escalate this?  Since Bluemix force removed containers, it impacted our application and with this Kubernetes issue, we could not remediate in time.

Comment: It turned out to be that this account was trial.  Will switch over to paid account.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need admin rights to create clusters in Bluemix. Just makes sure that you get the admin status and it should work for you. The normal permissions granted to you are that of an user. Hope this helps